# Cannot find view in the Mail::send facade when sending mail in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, email, view, laravel-5

I'm trying to send mail with Laravel 5.2 and I'm trying to do it with function `Mail::send`

```
Mail::send('reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
        $m->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');

        $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
    });
```

This is what i have in views/reminder.blade.php

```
Hello <?php echo $user->name; ?> this is your mail
```

Now when I try to use the method for this, it gives me the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [reminder] not found.
```

Can someone please explain to me why this happens and how can I fix this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you're specifying that the blade template you want to use is called `reminder` and it needs to be in the root of the `resources/views` directory.

```
Mail::send('reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
    $m->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');

    $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
});
```

It's likely that your view is in another directory, people often put their email templates in `resources/views/mail` or similar so they are separated from other types of view. In this case, you would use Laravel's dot notation to specify a directory:

```
Mail::send('mail.reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
    $m->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');

    $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
});
```

I would assume that your view isn't in the root of the `resources/views` directory so would either need to be placed there, or you should use dot notation to specify which directory the view is in.